# Modify ng-messages directive to only show when field is $dirty

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-messages

I currently use markup like this for all my ng-messages

```
<div ng-messages="myForm.fieldName.$error && (myForm.firldName.$dirty || myForm.$submitted)">
    <div ng-message="required">This field is required</div>
    <div ng-message="minlength">Your field is too short</div>
</div>
```

It's a bit messy though and I'd like to somehow override or extend ng-messages so that it automatically checks to see whether the field is dirty or the form that the field is nested inside (by walking up the DOM maybe?) is $submitted.

I'd like this to be the default behaviour on all ng-messages in my site and can't forsee a situation when I'd need to show error messages when the input hadn't been used and the form hadn't been submitted so I think it's safe to override that behaviour, I just don't know how to do it.

I know I can replace the ng-messages entirely but then I'd have to recreate all of the default behaviours of that directive and these might change in future angular versions so I'd rather just extend it if possible. I don't know whether Angular provides any hooks for this (I've vaguely heard of decorator methods?) or whether to make a sibling directive, something like "ng-custom-messages" which just hides the element if the conditions aren't met?

So, I have a couple of ideas but I need a bit of a nudge to show how to implement them, just a bit of skeleton code if anybody is feeling charitable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this was unfortunately to write a new form directive which automaticalley set all fields to dirty when submission happens.

Here is a short snippet of code...

```
angular.forEach( formCtrl , function ( formElement , fieldName ) {

    if ( fieldName[0] === '$' ){
        return;
    } 

    formElement.$setDirty();

}, this);

formCtrl.$setDirty();
scope.$apply();
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend instead using an `ngIf` on the element that uses the `ngMessages`. Note that `ngMessages` accepts the `$error` property of `NgModelController` (or `FormController`).

```
<div ng-if="myForm.fieldName.$invalid && (myForm.fieldName.$dirty || myForm.$submitted)"
        ng-messages="myForm.fieldName.$error">
    <div ng-message="required">This field is required</div>
    <div ng-message="minlength">Your field is too short</div>
</div>
```

As an aside, you may find it more appropriate to use `$touched` instead of `$dirty` in order to postpone error feedback until the element *has lost focus* (or the form has been submitted).